# Uncountable sets on $(0,\infty)$ also uncountable on $[b,\infty]$ for some $b > 0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this true?  Let $A$ be an uncountable set on $(0,\infty)$.  Then there is a number $b > 0$  such that $B = A \bigcap [b,\infty)$ is uncountable.

I started by considering a sequence $b_n \rightarrow 0$ generating sets $B_n = A \bigcap [b_n, \infty)$.  If every $B_n$ is countable, must $A$ be countable?  While this seems reasonable, I'm not sure I can conclude this.

Comment: Yes the countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: You're method of solution is valid. $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$, so if every $B_n$ is countable then $A$ is at most countable.

Comment: It's not difficult to enumerate a countable union of countable sets. You start with element one from the first set. Then you take element one from the second set and element two from the first. Then you take element one from the third set, element two from the second set and element three from the first. This is continued in the obvious manner, and we see that any element is enumerated at some finite stage.

Comment: Gregory Grant and basket are saying the same thing of course, and I didn't think of it that way  That surely nails it.

Comment: Very helpful, Arthur.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Observe that
$$
A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\big(A\cap(1/n,\infty)\big).
$$
If $A\cap(1/n,\infty)$ were countable, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then so would be $A$.